# Overview of set/vector/mapping operations for use with accademic pseudocode

Tags: algorithm, pseudocode

I am a PhD student -- In accademia people often describe algorithms using pseudocode. Structures like vectors, sets and mappings crop up very often. Is there a comprehensive list of operations one can perform on such data structures somewhere?

Thanks

Comment: You should try asking at http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/

Comment: It is most likely going to be closed on cstheory. Besides, the question is quite vague.

Answer (score 0):

As I've found, while teaching Algorithms and Data-structures, there is no "one right standard" for such set of operations. As an example, in some places all containers have "empty()" in others not. Everything depends on you teaching goals and lecture program. Think, what you would like to stress out, when teaching. Think, what minimal, but understandable set of operations is adequate to algorithms you would like to show. No metter, what are you going to show (maybe lecture reference materials are right place to check-out first), I think it's worth to give students references to [SGI's STL documentation](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/). As they might like to find their knowledge useful, or experiment with shown stuff. I recommend students C++, as I and they find it much better (faster, comfortable) for implementing algorithms, than java (ok, python seems good for academic purposes as well, but it "hides" a lot of complexity issues, while students should be aware).